# Recover Windows 11 encrypted files

Tags: windows

Context: Reinstall Windows 11 (clean reinstall) on C drive. My data is on D drive.

Problem: Some of my files on D are encrypted (not aware of this, particularly the "Pictures" folder) and I can't access them. I have the username/password of the old account on the old Windows, which is now no longer there.

Question: Is there a way to recover my encrypted files?

More information:
Properties > Security Tab
[Properties > Security Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewPgg.png)
Properties > General Tab > Advanced > Details
[Properties > General Tab > Advanced > Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAJsK.png)

Comment: Do you know whether they were secured using EFS certificates or perhaps its just an ACL issue. Please post an image of `Properties > Security Tab`.

Comment: How are they encrypted? BitLocker, Veracrypt...

Comment: If you had EFS (Encrypted File System) and you failed to export the certificate before you reinstalled Windows, then the files are permanently encrypted without any way to decrypt them.

Comment: I've added the Properties > Security Tab and Properties > General Tab > Advanced > Details images.
There's some information on the Internet about Decryption tools that can decrypt ransom-encrypted files. Just wondering how they work and can the same method be applied here.

Comment: Can you post information similar to the image I posted in your question.

Comment: Properties > Security Tab? It's on the edited post.

Comment: I think you are out of luck as this looks like an EFS encrypted file. When you reinstalled the OS, the security certificate was deleted. There is one more thing to try just to make sure the problem is a lost certificate versus an ACL issue. Go to one of the encrypted files and go to `SECURITY TAB > ADVANCED`. In the advanced dialogue box, change the owner to your current user name and hit `okay`. Then go back into advanced and click `Change Permission` and then `Add` and add your current username and give yourself full permissions. `Okay` out of everything and try to open the file.

Comment: Yeah, still can't open it given the owner and full permission. It is an EFS encrypted file.
Should I keep the files hoping that in the future there will be a way to decrypt them (quantum computing / Decryption tools that can recover ransom-encrypted files)?

Comment: There are commercial products out there that claim to be able to recover EFS that have lost their certificate. I do not know how good or effective any of them might be. So, whether you want to keep in hopes of a future solution is really a personal question. For me it would depend on how important the files really were in the grand scheme of things and how much money I would be willing to risk to see if any of these commercial programs work.

Comment: @Brian - Those commercial products absolutely CANNOT decrypt encrypted files without the certificate used to encrypt them.

Comment: @Ramhound - I assume that to be the case. That's why I added words such as "claim to be able," "I do not know how good or effective..."

Comment: They are not even worth mentioning. We have a user, who knows nothing about EFS, and now has files they will never be able to recover for that reason.  There isn't a sense to give them hope they can access the files when it does not actually exist.

Comment: It would take a super computer months or years (more likely LOTS of years) in order to come up with the key necessary to unlock. Encryption is a good thing for protecting your data, but backing up that data is also important, especially because good encryption is effectively impossible to crack, even after accidents like this.